# Why has my question gained an oddly high number of views?

Tags: discussion

I'm still fairly new to this Stack, but I've been trying to get involved with writing good questions and answers, and I decided to [ask a question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75636/why-are-adam-and-eve-considered-married) that had been on my mind for a while.

Relatively quickly, it got an answer that pointed out I had mis-remembered the relevant passage in Genesis, and that the answer was clearly in the text. I accepted the answer straight away (without waiting 24hr), because I didn't see much point in leaving such a simple question open.

Today, I've discovered that the question has earned me the "Popular Question" badge, as it's had over 1000 views. Looking at other new questions, that's order of magnitude higher than the average question, which barely reach 20 views. Given it was answered relatively simply, it doesn't feel like a question that deserves such an anomalous number of views.

Can anyone with more experience on this stack, and possibly access to statistics (if such things exist), suggest a reason why this question in particular has been viewed so many times?

Comment: Interesting observation. Not to beat on a dead horse, but I suspect people's interest that snowballed into HNQ also suggests that it's not as obvious a question as it appears :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It became one of the [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot).

The exact criteria for a question to become a hot network question [is complicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/256282), but if a question gets quite a few votes as well as (I think) at least two answers which also get a few votes, then it has a chance to become a HNQ, which will then be shown on other sites in the network.

[image: Screenshot of the hot network questions section of the side bar]

Comment: Actually the [formula is published](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/what-are-the-criteria-for-questions-to-be-selected-for-hot-network-questions/61343#61343), although it's [recently been tweaked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/updating-the-hot-network-questions-list-now-with-a-bit-more-network-and-a-litt).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks!